# undefined method using 'each' method Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I receive undefined method error on 'each' for nil:NilClass.

Here's the controller

```
class UserController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @users = User.all
  end
end
```

the view (edited)

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
  <td><%= @user.name %></td>
  <td><%= @user.nip %></td>
  <td><%= @user.job %></td>
  <td>Verifikasi berkas<span class="pull-right-container">
    <a href="#"><small class="pull-right"><button type="button"
       class="btn btn-block btn-info">NEXT</button></small></a></span>
  </td>
<% end %>
```

Here's the model. It's just a single table because i just want to see if it's work or not

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
end
```

the route

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :user
  root 'user#index'
end
```

When I try `@users = User.first` and print `@users.name` in the controller, it's working. So how to use 'each' method properly? please help thank you

Comment: Inside the loop the block variable is `user`, not `@users`, which is your collection.

Comment: this question is solved by a typo fix; voting to close: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319399/closing-questions-with-typos-faster-typo-hammer

Comment: whoever is downvoting the answers, you don't need to downvote

Comment: Downvotes should be reserved for unequivocally wrong or misleading answers, not because you don't like the question.

Comment: It may not be a `typo` but a misunderstanding of OP of how `each` block works.

Comment: exactly, this will lead the users to not answer this type of questions

Comment: sorry, there is a typo when i wrote in this post but i already get the answer. the '@' tag is not required. thank you

Comment: Not `@user`, `user`, just as you've named it in the block parameter.

Comment: free rep and karma for fixing a typo? not sure I like that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `user` variable instead of `@users` inside the block

```
 <%= @users.each do |user| %>
   <td><%= user.name %></td>
   <td><%= user.nip %></td>
   <td><%= user.job %></td>
   <td>Verifikasi berkas<span class="pull-right-container">
       <a href="#"><small class="pull-right"><button type="button"
       class="btn btn-block btn-info">NEXT</button></small></a></span>
   </td>
 <% end %>
```

Also,

It's not part of the question asked but, You might need to change the route as well

```
resources :users
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that problem is in `each`? can you show your console log? how about this?

```
<%= @users.each do |user| %>
   <td><%= user.name %></td>
   <td><%= user.nip %></td>
   <td><%= user.job %></td>
   <td>Verifikasi berkas<span class="pull-right-container">
     <a href="#"><small class="pull-right"><button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-info">NEXT</button></small></a></span>
  </td>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<%= @users.each do |user| %>]
   <tr>
   <td><%= user.name %></td>
   <td><%= user.nip %></td>
   <td><%= user.job %></td>
   <td>Verifikasi berkas<span class="pull-right-container">
       <a href="#"><small class="pull-right"><button type="button"
       class="btn btn-block btn-info">NEXT</button></small></a></span>
   </td>
   </tr>
 <% end %>
```

When you iterate through `@users` and specify the block variable `user` you're specifying that for each record returned, it can be referenced as `user`... see the code above.

You also need a `<tr></tr>` to put each record in its own line on the table.

Answer (score 0):

I edit your code and you can paste it to your code base and i hope it will be work.

Here's the edited controller (app/controllers/users_controller.rb)

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @users = User.all
  end
end
```

Here's the edited view (app/views/users/index.html.erb)

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
  <td><%= user.name %></td>
  <td><%= user.nip %></td>
  <td><%= user.job %></td>
  <td>Verifikasi berkas<span class="pull-right-container">
    <a href="#"><small class="pull-right"><button type="button"
       class="btn btn-block btn-info">NEXT</button></small></a></span>
  </td>
<% end %>
```

Here's the model (app/models/user.rb)

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
end
```

Here's the route (config/routes.rb)

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :users
  root 'users#index'
end
```